# Repeatedly Getting "Cannot find module" error

Tags: windows-10, python, node.js, python3

I have installed a package called `munch` on Windows 10 from [here](https://github.com/ccampbell/html-muncher).

However I am not able to execute a command. When I say on the command line

```
munch --help
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

I checked out AppData and found that munch was installed at:

[image]

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/1509809)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is finding another program named `munch`.  Note that the `munch` you installed is a Python script, and the `munch` reporting the error is a node.js script.  Try:

```
where munch
```

This will give you any `munch` command on the PATH.  If one of them is `munch.py`, then you can use the full path to run the script, or you can adjust the PATH environment variable so that the desired much is first on the path.

Or if the `munch` in your picture is the correct one, you can try:

```
C:\Users\Nitro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pyton36\Scripts\munch --help
```